# Need to authenticate user

Tags: android, authentication

I want to authenticate the user using some process on the Android Device.

**Process 1**
Using Finger Print Scan on the device ( I Dont whether it was possible or not)

**Process 2** Ask the User to type the some user ID or some unique Id

Or Else plz suggest any best way to authenicate the user

Comment: Is this your home work? You haven't tried anything?

Comment: Its an idea of my semester project